# Present perfect + Just after

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

Is the following expression grammatically correct ? If so, does it sound natural ?

> I've corrected it, just after I've seen it.

Thanks .

**Update :**

Here is the scenario :

My friend has sent me an email with a text to correct . So, I have checked the text out after a while from the reception time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**just after I've seen it** is a non-starter unless it's referring to something which has not yet taken place.

> I will tell you whether I wish to buy your car just after I've seen it.

There, I have not seen your car yet.

So, if you already saw it before you corrected it:

> I corrected it, just after I **saw** it.
>
> I corrected it, just after I **had seen** it.

***The time-expression in a present-perfect construction cannot exclude the present.***

The phrases

**just after I saw it** or **just after I had seen it**

refer to the *past*.

So we cannot say:

> I **have corrected** it *just after I saw it|just after I had seen it*.  <sup>NO</sup>

We must say

> I **corrected** it just after ...

Answer (score 2):

No, your suggested answer is NOT idiomatic.

The double *present perfect* doesn't work with *just after*.

It would be fine to say:

> I have seen it and I have corrected it

or

> I've seen it and corrected it.

but both of these omit the *just after*.

Your options in this instance, assuming you want to emphasise the immediacy, are:

> I corrected it just after I had seen it.

or

> I corrected it just after I saw it

or

> I corrected it just after seeing it.

All are idiomatic, with little to choose between them, and just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have seen it, I have corrected it.

Here is an example which is grammatically correct.

Present tense has current relevance so when you use it as you did it is confusing.

The way I used it makes it sound as if this is a practice of mine that I still engage in. Thus, giving it current relevanc. I hope that helps!